# Resolver ecuación matemática desde TextBox en VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Necesito ayuda con el siguiente problema:

Tengo tres `TextBox`.

1. `PRECIOTextBox` que contiene un número
2. `FORMULATextBox` que contiene una fórmula matemática como "+10%*2"
3. `PRECIO_ATextBox` que debería mostrar el resultado de la fórmula matemática entre el primer y segundo `TextBox`

Hasta ahora sólo logré trabajar con porcentajes y resolver fórmulas como "+10%+20%". Pero me encuentro en un problema cuando a esa fórmula se agregan símbolos de multiplicación y división.
Les dejo el código que tengo hasta ahora:

```
Dim FormulaA As String = FORMULA_ATextBox.Text
Dim FormulaASeparado() As String
Dim Precio1 As Double = PRECIOTextBox.Text
FormulaASeparado = FormulaA.Split("%")

  For x = 0 To FormulaASeparado.Length - 1
      If FormulaASeparado(x).ToString <> "" Then
          If Val(FormulaASeparado(x)) > 0 Then
              Precio1 = Precio1 + (Precio1 * Val(FormulaASeparado(x)) / 100)
          Else
              Precio1 = Precio1 - (Precio1 * Math.Abs(Val(FormulaASeparado(x))) / 100)
          End If
      End If
  Next

PRECIO_ATextBox.Text = Precio1
```

Sería de gran ayuda si alguien puede colaborar. Hace semanas estoy trabado en esto jaja! Gracias!

**EDIT -------**

Finalmente pude resolverlo con Expresiones regulares. Dejo el código por si a alguien le sirve:

```
        ' Definimos las expresiones regulares
    Dim Valor As String = FORMULA_ATextBox.Text
    Dim matchesP1 As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(Valor, "\+\d+%")
    Dim matchesP2 As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(Valor, "\-\d+%")
    Dim matchesM As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(Valor, "\*\d+")
    Dim matchesD As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(Valor, "\/\d+")
    Dim Precio As Double = PRECIOTextBox.Text
    Dim PrecioA As Double = PRECIO_ATextBox.Text

    ' Si encuentra % postivo
    For Each m As Match In matchesP1
        For Each c As Capture In m.Captures
            Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("\d+")
            Dim match1 As Match = regex.Match(c.Value)
            PrecioA = PrecioA + (PrecioA * match1.Value / 100)
        Next
        PRECIO_ATextBox.Text = PrecioA
    Next

    ' Si encuentra % negativo
    For Each m As Match In matchesP2
        For Each c As Capture In m.Captures
            Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("\d+")
            Dim match1 As Match = regex.Match(c.Value)
            PrecioA = PrecioA - (PrecioA * match1.Value / 100)
        Next
        PRECIO_ATextBox.Text = PrecioA
    Next

    ' Si encuentra *
    For Each m As Match In matchesM
        For Each c As Capture In m.Captures
            Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("\d+")
            Dim match1 As Match = regex.Match(c.Value)
            PrecioA = PrecioA * match1.Value
        Next
        PRECIO_ATextBox.Text = PrecioA
    Next

    ' Si encuentra /
    For Each m As Match In matchesD
        For Each c As Capture In m.Captures
            Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("\d+")
            Dim match1 As Match = regex.Match(c.Value)
            PrecioA = PrecioA / match1.Value
        Next
        PRECIO_ATextBox.Text = PrecioA
    Next
```

Gracias a todos por la ayuda!

Comment: Luciano, tu pregunta es buena, pero me parece a mi que tu problema es demasiado amplio, y quizas necesitamos saber mas cosas. ¿la "formula" siempre va a tener un signo de porcentaje? Porque si no tuviera uno, tu ciclo for nunca se ejecutaria. Supongo que es importante la jerarquia de operaciones, ¿podrias confirmarlo? Tambien, es posible que la "formula" contenga numeros decimales? ¿La formula acepta parentesis? ¿Existe algún formato prestablecido que la formula siempre vaya a tener o se puede introducir cualquier cosa?

Comment: Hola Kenny, gracias por contestar.
La fórmula no siempre va a tener un signo de porcentaje. Es probable que sólo contenga un símbolo de multiplicación o división.
También puede contener números decimales.
No debería aceptar paréntesis.

Es una tabla con ítems que tienen un precio. La idea es que exista un precio A que sea resultado de una fórmula como la que expuse.

Comment: Con tu código actual, si alguien mete algo sin %, me parece que FormulaASeparado.Length daria como resultado 0 y aunque no estoy familiarizado con vb.net, creo que tu ciclo for se ejecutaria 0 veces, y por lo tanto cualquier otra verificacion dentro del ciclo no tendria sentido. El problema es bonito, pero creo que tienes que analizar un poco mejor el problema y tratar de descomponerlo en partes. Una vez tuve que resolver algo similar (hablando de entender operaciones matematicas desde un string) y encontre que una buena forma para resolverlo era con recursividad.

Comment: Si realmente no sabes por donde empezar, o no estas familiarizado con otros conceptos y dada la extensión del problema, quizas te seria bueno darte una vuelta por el [chat]. :D

Comment: En realidad, si escribo "+10" lo que hace mi código es ejecutar el ciclo "a * b / 100" para dar el porcentaje. El código que escribí sólo funciona para dar con porcentajes. Al principio pensé que iba bien esa solución, pero luego me encontré con la posibilidad de hacer divisiones, multiplicaciones, sumas y restas en la fórmula.

Comment: Si lo has resuelto,en lugar de editarlo en la pregunta,añade una respuesta y aceptala (tendrás que esperar dos dias para ello)

Answer (score 1):

Creo que estás tomando un rumbo equivocado. Debes estar asumiendo que los caracteres `+` y `-` significan suma y resta para el compilador, cuando en realidad, la formula que vos pones, se interpreta como "***numero positivo***" o "***numero negativo***" . La forma correcta seria usar *IF* para pasar por distintos caminos, te paso un **pseudocodigo** para que me entiendas

```
IF(texto.contains("+")) then resultado=a+b

IF(texto.contains("-")) then resultado=a-b

IF(texto.contains("*")) then resultado=a*b

IF(texto.contains("/")) then resultado=a/b
```

> #### Nota:
>
> Para extraer el carácter operador vas a tener que hacer **split** pasando uno de los caracteres (`+-/*`).
>
> Fíjate también que  `indexOf ( )`  y `substring()` para recortar textos te pueden servir.

Comment: Hola Luis! Gracias por contestar. Creo entender la lógica, pero no sé bien cómo aplicarla. Voy a probar y cualquier cosa edito mi pregunta.
Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Tengo la impresión de que el problema no está bien planteado: si el primer textbox contiene el valor de una variable, el segundo textbox debería contener una fórmula que incluyera el nombre de una variable (x o y). Aún así, el problema no sería fácil del plantear. ¿Por qué intentas crear una matriz cuyos elementos están separados por tantos por ciento?

Si se trata de especificar tantos por ciento, el problema es sencillo:

x = 5
t = 5%
y = 5 * (1 + t/100)
En el primer textbox, la cantidad. En el segundo, el tanto por ciento (hay que eliminar el símbolo de porcentaje de la cantidad leída). El resultado sería el producto de aplicar a la cantidad el incremento señalado por el porcentaje.